# Using the selected item from a DropDownList in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Currently I am programming a editor for a little game we are making, you will be able to add questions to a API.

I want to use a combobox to select a type of question(Text, text + picture, etc.)
I can't seem to let the combobox work with the selected item.
How can I filter on the selecteditem?

(The textboxes are hardcoded, pardon me for that)

You can find the code down here.

```
private void TypeSelectbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TypeSelectbox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Tekst")
        {

            #region Vraag Textbox and Label

            TextBox VraagTB = new TextBox();
            VraagTB.Width = 400;
            VraagTB.Location = new Point(370, 90);
            this.Controls.Add(VraagTB);

            Label VraagLb = new Label();
            VraagLb.Width = 500;
            VraagLb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            VraagLb.Location = new Point(370, 70);
            VraagLb.Text = "Wat wordt de vraag die U wilt toevoegen?";
            this.Controls.Add(VraagLb);

            #endregion

            #region Antwoord TextBoxes (A t/m D)

            TextBox Antwoord_A = new TextBox();
            Antwoord_A.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_A.Location = new Point(370, 200);
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_A);

            TextBox Antwoord_B = new TextBox();
            Antwoord_B.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_B.Location = new Point(600, 200);
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_B);

            TextBox Antwoord_C = new TextBox();
            Antwoord_C.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_C.Location = new Point(600, 280);
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_C);

            TextBox Antwoord_D = new TextBox();
            Antwoord_D.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_D.Location = new Point(370, 280);
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_D);

            #endregion

            #region Antwoord Labels (A t/m D)
            Label Antwoord_A_Lb = new Label();
            Antwoord_A_Lb.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_A_Lb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Antwoord_A_Lb.Location = new Point(370, 180);
            Antwoord_A_Lb.Text = "Het antwoord voor optie A";
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_A_Lb);

            Label Antwoord_B_Lb = new Label();
            Antwoord_B_Lb.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_B_Lb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Antwoord_B_Lb.Location = new Point(600, 180);
            Antwoord_B_Lb.Text = "Het antwoord voor optie B";
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_B_Lb);

            Label Antwoord_C_Lb = new Label();
            Antwoord_C_Lb.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_C_Lb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Antwoord_C_Lb.Location = new Point(370, 260);
            Antwoord_C_Lb.Text = "Het antwoord voor optie C";
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_C_Lb);

            Label Antwoord_D_Lb = new Label();
            Antwoord_D_Lb.Width = 150;
            Antwoord_D_Lb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Antwoord_D_Lb.Location = new Point(600, 260);
            Antwoord_D_Lb.Text = "Het antwoord voor optie D";
            this.Controls.Add(Antwoord_D_Lb);
            #endregion

        }
```

Comment: First off, hey Dutchie :P. Second, what doesn't work? You only check for type text now, does the code add the controls in that case?

Comment: What sort of application is this? Winforms, web, WPF?

Comment: From [documentation of DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx): Use the SelectedIndex property to programmatically determine the index of the item selected by the user from the DropDownList control. The index can then be used to retrieve the selected item from the **Items** collection of the control.

Comment: It depends on how you bind the ComboBox. If you use `DisplayMember` property and `ValueMember` then the `SelectedItem` is an object that is loaded from the `DataSource` property, if you bind them to a list of strings and add the items manually then your approach is correct.

Comment: Hi guys, I've found the solution myself now.  Thanks for all the fast responses! I used: if (TypeSelectBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Tekst") to make it work.